# TempDB has reached its size quota: How to increase size quota for tempDB on Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are getting an error while loading data from one table to another. We do some monthly/quarterly roll ups on the first table data which is inserted into another table

The source table has clustered column store index.
We have billions of rows in the source data table.

the `SELECT` part of the load script has a WHERE clause which filters data based on month and year.

The error is below

> 'The database 'tempdb' has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions.'

Comment: I'm not sure that you can but it would be good if someone can point to the documented limits. I was looking for these recently and didn't find anything up to date and authoratitive.

Comment: I'm curious if you can show a screenshot of the "usage" tab on the Azure SQL database.  Does it show the database size at the time that you are doing the copy?

Comment: @MartinSmith:i found these,let me know if you think these are not authoratitive or you have found the same earlier

Comment: You should probably fix the query so it doesn't have to spill out to tempdb. Did you check the execution plan? What does the query do? How much data do you have to move?

Comment: @thegame I think I did come across those but wasn't sure what to make of the `acom-feature-videos-twitter-card.azurewebsites.net` domain. Looks like it is probably official!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLAzure enforces different limits,some are applicable irrespective of tiers,some limits may be higher depending on your service tier.Below is the way Azure handles those limits

### Enforcement of limits

Resources other than CPU, Memory, Log I/O, and Data I/O are enforced by denying new requests when limits are reached. When a database reaches the configured maximum size limit, inserts and updates that increase data size fail, while selects and deletes continue to work. Clients receive an error message depending on the limit that has been reached.

so this answers your question on whether we can increase size of TEMPDB

Below are the limits   for TEMPDB

[image]

This Page [Azure SQL Database Resource Limits](https://acom-feature-videos-twitter-card.azurewebsites.net/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-resource-limits/#tempdb) contains entire Limits in detail, i will try to add all the details when time permits or when i find the Github page ,so that link rot can be avoided